# Design Pattern to use with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am working on creating a Technical Design Document for my new project that is being developed using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First.

I want my DAL to be to be loosely coupled, easily testable and should be able to dynamically inject it using IoC Container...

Thinking of using Repository Pattern. Are there any good resources for reference?

--

Preetham Reddy

Comment: What you mean by "DAL to be easily testable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty good post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 4):

See these tutorials:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control-part-2-adding-a-business-logic-layer-and-unit-tests